# Apache mod_rewrite, multiple variables

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite, regex

I'm struggling a bit with mod_rewrite and replacing multiple variables with regexes. I'm trying to rewrite the following:

```
www.mysite.com/avatars/funny/1
```

into:

```
www.mysite.com/avatars.php?genre=funny&page=1
```

Right now I have the following, which isn't really doing the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^/avatars/?(.*)/?(.*)$ /avatars.php?genre=$1&page=$2
```

Answer (score 4):

The `*` operator is greedy.  This means that it will grab as much as it possibly can.

In your example, the first `(.*)` block will match `/funny/1`.  The second one will match nothing at all, but that's OK because `*` matches "zero or more" of the preceding character.

Using a different block to match the parts in between the slashes will do the trick.  Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/avatars/([a-z]*)/([0-9]*)$ /avatars.php?genre=$1&page=$2
```

or this:

```
RewriteRule ^/avatars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /avatars.php?genre=$1&page=$2
```

There's also no need for the `?` operator after the slashes as in order for there to be two variables, the slashes must be there.

---

Apache also has *reluctant* operators which are the opposite of greedy operators.  You can use these by adding a question mark after a normally greedy operator.  Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/avatars/(.*?)/(.*?)$ /avatars.php?genre=$1&page=$2
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved some issues. However, if I navigate to mysite.com/avatars with this rule, i get a 404.

Comment: Are you expecting to load the `/avatars.php` file when you request `/avatars` ?  If so, that might explain what the question marks after the slashes were doing in your original rule.  I would go with an extra rewrite rule: `RewriteRule ^/avatars/?$ /avatars.php [L]`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `?` since the slashes are not optional. However, you probably need to stop processing once this rule is applied ([L]). Can you try the following?

```
RewriteRule ^/avatars/(.*)/(.*)$ /avatars.php?genre=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of /? is the problem, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^avatars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ avatars.php?genre=$1&page=$2 [L]
```